# How to get values from HashMap?

Tags: hashmap

I want to get properteis from HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Object> getProperties()
```

I want to get the properties which is true.

Comment: Try google before you ask please !

Comment: i did but i couldnt find any good answer and im pretty new in android..

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
newMap.put("property", "shhh_secret");
String value = newMap.get("property");
```

or

```
Set s = newMap.keySet();  
for (Iterator iter = s.iterator(); iter.hasNext())  {  
  newMap.get(s);  
}
```

or

```
Iterator iter = newMap.keySet().iterator();  
while (iter.hasNext()) {  
          ... 
}
```

[Source and more examples](http://web.archive.org/web/20120626192725/http://www.stanford.edu/group/coursework/docsTech/jgl/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashMapExamples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Question which can help you :

[How to Get Values from List of HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358853/how-to-get-values-from-list-of-hashmap)

[get string value from HashMap depending on key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789679/get-string-value-from-hashmap-depending-on-key-name)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/407505/java/java/Retrieve-values-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

This will help to read values from HashMap..Simple example

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    hm.put(1, "One");
    hm.put(2, "Two");
    hm.put(3, "Three");

    Set st = hm.entrySet(); //hm.keySet();
    for(Iterator itr = st.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
    {
        //hm.get(st);
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```